# MySQL, struggling with queries

Tags: mysql

Here is my current query

```
SELECT sub.Name, sub.playlistid
FROM (SELECT TrackId, playlistId, track.name AS Name
  FROM playlisttrack NATURAL JOIN track
ORDER BY TrackId) AS sub
```

This returns the following.

```
Name   PlaylistID
For Those About To Rock (We Salute You) 8
For Those About To Rock (We Salute You) 17
For Those About To Rock (We Salute You) 1
Balls to the Wall   1
Balls to the Wall   8
Balls to the Wall   17
Fast As a Shark 8
Fast As a Shark 1
Fast As a Shark 17
Fast As a Shark 5
```

I can't figure out how to do a count so it would do something like

```
Name    NumberofPlaylists
For Those About To Rock (We Salute You) 3
Balls to the Wall   3
Fast as a Shark 4
```

Whenver I do a count it just gives me

```
For Those About To Rock (We Salute You) 8715 (total amount of tuples)\
```

SIMILAR PROBLEM

I am able to get this far.

```
SELECT sub.BillingCountry, sub.aid, sub.title
  FROM(SELECT BillingCountry, Title, album.AlbumId AS aid#Count oftime purchased in that country
    From album natural join track Natural join invoiceline NATURAL JOIN invoice
    ORDER BY AlbumId) as sub
Order BY sub.aid, sub.billingcountry
```

and this is what I get

```
Brazil  1   For Those About To Rock We Salute You
Canada  1   For Those About To Rock We Salute You
Canada  1   For Those About To Rock We Salute You
Italy   1   For Those About To Rock We Salute You
Italy   1   For Those About To Rock We Salute You
Italy   1   For Those About To Rock We Salute You
Norway  1   For Those About To Rock We Salute You
Norway  1   For Those About To Rock We Salute You
Norway  1   For Those About To Rock We Salute You
Norway  1   For Those About To Rock We Salute You
Canada  2   Balls to the Wall
Germany 2   Balls to the Wall
```

However, now I want to count the times a certain country purchased something so what I want returned is

```
Norway 4 For those about to rock we salute you
...
```

Is this going to be similar?

```
select distinct a.country,b.playlist,a.cnt from
(select country,count(1) as cnt  from yourtable group by country) as a

left join

(select * from  (SELECT sub.BillingCountry, sub.aid, sub.title
                    FROM(SELECT BillingCountry, Title, album.AlbumId AS aid
                        From album natural join track Natural join invoiceline NATURAL JOIN invoice
                        Order BY sub.aid, sub.billingcountry)) as b 
on a.country = b.country
```

Answer (score 0):

I use you example try this:

```
select a.BillingCountry,cnt, b.title from
(select a.BillingCountry,count(1) as cnt from
(SELECT sub.BillingCountry, sub.aid, sub.title
  FROM(SELECT BillingCountry, Title, album.AlbumId AS aid#Count oftime purchased in that country
    From album natural 
    join track Natural 
    join invoiceline NATURAL 
    JOIN invoice
    ORDER BY AlbumId) as sub
Order BY sub.aid, sub.billingcountry) as a group by a.BillingCountry) as a

left join

(select sub.BillingCountry, sub.aid, sub.title from 
(SELECT sub.BillingCountry, sub.aid, sub.title
  FROM(SELECT BillingCountry, Title, album.AlbumId AS aid#Count oftime purchased in that country
    From album natural 
    join track Natural 
    join invoiceline NATURAL 
    JOIN invoice
    ORDER BY AlbumId) as sub
Order BY sub.aid, sub.billingcountry) as b
on a.BillingCountry = b.BillingCountry
```

Comment: I added to the bottom of it.  Would it have to be a similar answer to that?

Comment: what do you mean similar?

Comment: For my second problem in the original post.  I get to where I show and then I can't seem to count what I am trying to.

Comment: I edited the original post.  Is that what you meant.  I get an error asking for a ')' after the AS b when I do that.

Comment: what is the result of your first query is that working? and you need just to count the result? i think your query not working anymore. much better to add more data here and expected result.

Comment: What I posted above my results.  I just need it to count those so it shows how many times a country buys an album

Comment: just give the complete result of your first query.. ok seen it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT track.name 
    , COUNT(*)
FROM playlisttrack 
    NATURAL JOIN track
GROUP BY track.name
```

Comment: Ignore my comment.  Got it.